# implementing application indicator in notification bar blackberry phonegap

Tags: blackberry, notifications

We have a requirement in Blackberry to display application indicator when notification is received for a particular app,currently in background.On receiving a notification, a notification icon has to be displayed.On click of that notification icon, notification summary should display application icon and message to user informing him of new notification.Finally on click of application icon,the app has to be brought to foreground from background.

Currently we are able to display the notification icon,but we are unable to display application icon in notification bar.
The application is a hybrid app built using Phonegap.I have followed the steps as stated in the following link:-
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Application-Indicators-and-Home-Screen-Integration/ta-p/614919